# how to use "like" operator in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to check a sting(here date) in database column START_TIME using like operator android. Like let say START_TIME="09-09-2014, 11:33:01" and date = "09-09-2014" i want to take the other columns like DURATION in correspond to START_TIME value in column.

Here is my code:

```
public String getDuration(String date){
        SQLiteDatabase db=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns={DatabaseCreate.DURATION};
        String[] selectionArgs = {date};
        Cursor cursor=db.query(DatabaseCreate.USER_WORK_LOG, columns,
                DatabaseCreate.START_TIME+"=?%",selectionArgs,null,null,null);
        String duration="";
        int myNum = 0;
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            int index=cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseCreate.DURATION);
            duration=cursor.getString(index);
            //int index1=cursor.getColumnIn
            try {
                myNum += Integer.parseInt(duration);
            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
              // Handle parse error.
            }
        }

        int min = myNum%60;
        int hour = myNum/60;
        String hour_str = Integer.toString(hour);
        String min_str = Integer.toString(min);
        if(min<=9){
             min_str = "0"+min;
        }
        if(hour<10){
             hour_str = "0"+hour;
        }
        return hour_str+":"+min_str;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the cursor with:

```
Cursor cursor=db.query(DatabaseCreate.USER_WORK_LOG, columns,
            DatabaseCreate.START_TIME+" LIKE '"+date+"%'",null,null,null,null);
```

EDIT: Notice that you can run a regular SQL query on the database using the **rawQuery(...)** method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am getting this error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.

Comment: See the edited answer where the selectionArgs are nulled and the parameter is passed in the query.